# Animation automatically created by Rigify in Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, drivers, rigify, actions

After generating a rig with **Rigify** in Blender 2.83.3 an animation tab is added under the rig.
I'm quite new to blender, and I'm asking this question just to have more understanding of what I'm seeing and why it is there.

[image]

So as you can see from the image above, on the right side, I get an animation menu, below there is what is called **Drivers** which I have no idea about them ( if you can give me a hint on what they are I'll be eternally grateful ) and below it, there are **Squirrel** and **Squirrel_ui.py**.

1. Which are the functions of these things?
2. What are they?

Last but not least, there is that damn thing on the action editor that is created automatically. Is like a clone of the track above. I just can get rid of it, **can not delete it**. Why is this?

Guys thank you so much for your time.

**UPDATE**

[image]

About the **action editor** question: that extra tab, seems like a *copy* of the one above it. Also, I noticed that if I click on the button on the menu on top ( see screenshot ) which says "**Include missing NLA**", that block ( the one below ) just disappear, leaving visible only the one with the action inside. So from this test/result, I guess that this damn block is an **animation data-block** with no NLA data. How this block is created, why is created and why I can't delete it, well still a mystery. This may help you if you are looking into this as well.

About the drivers, I think they are part of the Rigify's code-structure, I think that they are needed in order for Rigfy to work. Still, I would love to know more details about it.